# Fragmentation on Heap With No Indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can fragmentation occur on a heap table with no non-clustered indexes?

Comment: I am struck by this question.  First and foremost, I associate fragmentation with deleting records.  Why do you associate it with non-clustered indexes?

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I could see it. Since a heap has, by def'n, no clustered index, if it has no non-clustered indexes, what is there to be fragmented? You and I know better, but everyone starts somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

***Yes, of course.***

A heap is also a collection of pages - and if pages aren't filled to 100% - you have (*internal*) fragmentation.

In addition - the heap is also shown as a *pseudo-index* (with id = 0) in the index catalog views and dynamic management views, and you can observe that it, too, can have (and most likely will have) fragmentation.

For more insights and background, see:

- [A SQL Server DBA myth a day: (29/30) fixing heap fragmentation](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/A-SQL-Server-DBA-myth-a-day-%282930%29-fixing-heap-fragmentation.aspx)
- [SQL Server Storage Engine Blog - Fragmentation (part 4): what are heaps?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/09/19/761437.aspx)
- [SQL SERVER – Fragmentation – Detect Fragmentation and Eliminate Fragmentation](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/01/12/sql-server-fragmentation-detect-fragmentation-and-eliminate-fragmentation/)
- [Heaps (on SQLServerPedia)](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/Heaps) with paragraphs on fragmentation and how to deal with it